# I used the TwitterOAuth library and got this error

Tags: php, twitter

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Composer\CaBundle\CaBundle' not found in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\CompleteWDC\cha10_APIs\twitter-api\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php:572 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CompleteWDC\cha10_APIs\twitter-api\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php(620): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->curlOptions() 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\CompleteWDC\cha10_APIs\twitter-api\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php(557): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->request('https://api.twi...', 'GET', 'Authorization: ...', Array, false) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\CompleteWDC\cha10_APIs\twitter-api\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php(490): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->oAuthRequest('https://api.twi...', 'GET', Array, false) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\CompleteWDC\cha10_APIs\twitter-api\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php(467): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->makeRequests('https://api.twi...', 'GET', Array, false) 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\CompleteWDC\cha10_APIs\twitter-api\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php(232): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->http('GET', 'h in C:\xampp\htdocs\CompleteWDC\cha10_APIs\twitter-api\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 572
```

I'm using it for the first time, so checked the TwitterOAuth.php file and line 572 then vscode says the CaBundle is undefined Type **Undefined type 'Composer\CaBundle\CaBundle'.** , I tried downloading the file over and over again but the same error.

Comment: Did you use composer to fetch the needed requisites of the library you intend to use?

Comment: Thanks @Ángel using composer solved the issue

Comment: I followed the steps in the accepted answer but still have the same issue. When I run composer show --all I get: installed: abraham/twitteroauth 6.2.0 The most popular PHP library for use with the Twitter OAuth REST API. composer/ca-bundle 1.3.7 Lets you find a path to the system CA bundle, and includes a fallback to the Mozilla CA bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem following the instructions on [here](https://twitteroauth.com/).

It turns out I wasn't including the right autoload. For those coming across the same problem:

1. Install composer locally on your directory as per these [instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/).
2. Run `php composer require abraham/twitteroauth`.
3. Run `php composer install`.
4. Make sure to include the right path to the composer autoloader file, not the package autoloader, in your PHP code `require "vendor/autoload.php";`.
5. In each file that you will be using the package, don't forget to include the line `use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth as TwitterOAuth;`, so that you can use `$foo = new TwitterOAuth()`;

I hope this helps those who might be new to composer like me.

Comment: I followed these steps and still get the same error. When I run composer show --all it says the libraries are installed correctly: installed:
  abraham/twitteroauth 6.2.0 The most popular PHP library for use with the Twitter OAuth REST API.
  composer/ca-bundle   1.3.7 Lets you find a path to the system CA bundle, and includes a fallback to the Mozilla CA bundle.